# how to calculate the difference between two exponential number

Tags: python

I want to use python to calculate the difference between two exponential number

```
a = 4,592e+9
b = 7,892e+9
c = b - a
print ('c = ',c)
```

I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: Float numbers are written with dot `.` not with a comma `,`. You should write `a = 4.592e+9`.

Comment: Python, like most languages, uses USer-style float constants.  The decimal point is a period (dot), rather than a comma.  Unfortunately, using a comma made each of your constants a pair (2-tuple) of numbers, such as (4,   592e+9).  A simple `print` statement would have shown you the values you had.

Comment: Thank you Sanyash and Prune for your help  It works now perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace the `,` with `.`

```
a = 4.592e+9
b = 7.892e+9
c = b - a
print ('c = ',c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing **,** with **.** will sort out your issue as you are trying to perform mathematical operations on a float value.

Working Code:

```
a = 4.592e+9
b = 7.892e+9
c = b - a
print ('c = ',c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because a and b are both [tuples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) not real [exponential numbers](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/scientific.html).
If you print the value of a you'd get `(4, 592000000000.0)`.
The problem is with the declaration of a and b, just change the `,` with `.`. 
So:

```
a = 4.592e+9
b = 7.892e+9
c = b - a 
print ('c = ',c)
```